# First argument that is without '-' has to be necessary

Tags: c, getopt

I am writing program that takes command line arguments but the first one is necessary and it is without a hyphen ("-"). Executing of application have to be:

```
./program <server> [-d] [-n]
```

I tried to make `argv[1]` (in this case is `server`) to be server but problem happens when server is somehow forgotten then it saves the option into server. How can I handle this or what should my `optstring` look like when first argument without a hyphen is needed?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html

Comment: Just brainstorming... I don't use `getopt()`. Maybe try `getopt(argc - 1, argv + 1, "options")`??

Comment: If it is required, then it is not an "option".

Comment: Guess you are right @WilliamPursell

Comment: Additionally, if you intend to insist that the required argument must appear before all options, then the command-line format that program requires is not consistent with the one supported by `getopt()`.  You might be able to persuade `getopt()` to process the options anyway, by the trick that @pmg described for example, but you should consider instead conforming to the standard POSIX convention, where non-option arguments come *after* all options, or to a relaxed convention (supported at least by GNU `getopt()`) where options and non-option arguments can be mixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your argument is not preceded by '-' then getopt won't recognize it.
You should handle the first argument by yourself doing something like this:

```c
if (!(argc >= 2 && argv[1][0] != '-'))
    errx(1, "Usage: ./program <server> [-d] [-n]");
```

And then you could use getopt as it will search for options that begin with '-' independently from the other values.

If you want to handle `-d` and `-n` options that do not take any value, your optstring should look like `"dn"` .